# Сбрасывается цикл for

Tags: матрицы, циклы, c++

Задача такова что мне надо найти столбец с минимальным произведением элементов. Двумерный массив зада динамически. Заполняю рандомными числами от 0 до 5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int **matrix;
int n,m,i,j,min,tmp=1;
bool flag=1;
cout<<"Enter 1-st size: ";
cin>>n;
cout<<"Enter 2-nd size: ";
cin>>m;
matrix=new int*[n];  //сюда будут сливаться адреса первых ячеек одномерных массивов
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  matrix[i]=new int[m];//одновременно выделяем место и присваиваем ссылку на первый элемент этого массива
      for(j=0;j<m;j++){
      matrix[i][j]=rand()%5; //заполняем рандомом от 0 до 5
      cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" "; //на экран
      }
  cout<<endl;
  }

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
tmp=tmp*matrix[j] [i];
}
if (flag) {
 min=tmp;
 flag=0;
}
if (tmp<min) {
 min=tmp;
}
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
delete [] matrix[i]; //освобождаем из памати все одномерные массивы
delete [] matrix;   //освоождаем место "главного" массива
getch();//стопорит консоль
return 0;

}
```

Суть проблемы состоит в том что по идее программа должна в первой итерациии перемножить элементы первого столбца а потом уже переходить к условиям, а программа выполняет один раз tmp=tmp*matrix[j] [i]; а потом сразу переходит к условиям. Надеюсь я подробно изложил суть

Comment: `tmp` надо инициализировать каждый раз внутри  цикла по столбцам, перед перебором строк.

--

Заодно с min запоминайте индекс столбца, которому соответствует min. По крайней мере самому проверять будет проще, да и ответ красивей -

что-то типа: "min произведение элементов равно 120 (в столбце 2)"

Comment: если пишите на с++ то мне кажется надо матрицу как класс оформить. так мне кажется проще будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int **matrix;
int n, m, i, j, min, tmp = 1;
bool flag = 1;
cout << "Enter 1-st size: ";
cin >> n;
cout << "Enter 2-nd size: ";
cin >> m;
matrix = new int*[n]; //сюда будут сливаться адреса первых ячеек одномерных массивов
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new int[m]; //одновременно выделяем место и присваиваем ссылку на первый элемент этого массива
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 5; //заполняем рандомом от 0 до 5
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " "; //на экран
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int column;

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    tmp = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        tmp = tmp * matrix[j][i];
    }
    if (flag) {
        min = tmp;
        column = i;
        flag = 0;
    }
    if (tmp < min) {
        min = tmp;
        column = i;
    }
}

cout << "column: " << column << endl << "multipl.: " << min << endl;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete [] matrix[i]; //освобождаем из памати все одномерные массивы
delete [] matrix; //освоождаем место "главного" массива
return 0;
```